# Конфликт TightVNC и WSUS на Win. Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wsus, vnc

Здравствуйте.
Появилась следующая проблема. На сервере стоит TightVNC и WSUS при попытке подключения по VNC виснет клиент VNC, при этом сервер виснет намертво (не серверная часть VNC, а именно сама ОСа). Опытным путем выяснил, что при отключении WSUS все работает нормально. Прошу Вашей помощи в решении данной проблемы.
Отказываться от VNC нет возможности (существует ряд задач, которые можно решить только с помощью VNC - по RDP не получается). Заранее спасибо.

---

**Дополнение**
Либо, как вариант, посоветуйте замену TightVNC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве замены TightVNC можно попробовать (в указанной очередности):

- [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/index.html) (Free Edition),
- [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/),
- [TigerVNC](http://www.tigervnc.com/).

Comment: UltraVNC помог, спасибо большое.